# Is there Python program that contains the main function and another function called CalcFun?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error when writing a Python program that contains the main function and another function called CalcFun.

The main function reads the student ID, student name, and student grades from the text file StudentGrades.txt and stores these values into three lists: stIdList, stNameList and stGradesList.

The stGradesList list for each student should be sent to the CalcFun function. In the CalcFun function,
the program should find the average of these grades and the letter grade based on the average using the following scale table.
The function should return the computed average and letter grade to the main function. In the main function and based on the returned values, the program should write to each line of a text-file results.txt the ID of a student, his name, his average, and his letter grade. Assume that the file StudentGrades.txt exists, so no need to check its existence.

```
def CalcFun(stGradesList): 
    total = 0.0
    grade=""
    #  average  = 0.0
    # for i in range(len(stGradesList)):
    average= sum(stGradesList)/len(stGradesList) 
    if(average>=90):
        grade="A"
    elif(average>=80): 
      grade="B"
    elif(average>=70): 
      grade="D"
    elif(average>=60): 
      grade="C"
    elif(average<=50): 
      grade="F"
    return average , grade  
   
def main():
    infile = open("StudentGrades.txt", "r")
    outfile = open("results.txt", "w")
    stIdList = []
    stNameList= []
    stGradesList= []
    line = infile.readline()
    while line != "" :
        currentline = line.split(";")
        stIdList = currentline[0]
        stNameList = currentline[1]
       for n in currentline[2]+currentline[3]+currentline[4]+currentline[5]:
            stGradesList.append(n)
   
    outfile.write("StudentID"+"          "+"Name"+"          "+"Average"+"          "+"LG")
    outfile.write("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    outfile.write("\n"+ stIdList)
    outfile.write("\n"+ stNameList)
    outfile.write("\n"+  CalcFun(stGradesList))

main()
```

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: This is not correct as I would like

Comment: It should be 
The main function reads the student ID, student name, and student grades from the text file StudentGrades.txt and stores these values into three lists: stIdList, stNameList and stGradesList. 
the program should write to each line of a text-file results.txt the ID of a student, his name, his average, and his letter grade. Assume that the file StudentGrades.txt exists, so no need to check its existence.